# Excel find and replace function correct formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to use the find and replace function in excel to remove example sentences from cells similar to this:

```
text <br>〔「text」text，「text」text〕<br>（１）text「sentence―sentence/sentence」<br>（２）text「sentence―sentence」
```

Sentences are in between 「」brackets and will include a ― and / character somewhere inside the brackets.
I have tried `「*―*/*」`  however this will delete everything from the right of the〔
Is there any way to target and delete these specific sentence brackets, with the find and replace tool?

Desired outcome:

```
text <br>〔「text」text，「text」text〕<br>（１）text<br>（２）text「sentence―sentence」
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a long formula but in Excel O365 you could use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(IF(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)="「","</s><s>「",IF(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)="」","」</s><s>",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))),"<br>","|$|")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(., '「') and contains(., '―') and contains(., '/') and contains(., '」'))][node()]")),"|$|","<br>")
```

As long as you have access to `CONCAT` you could also do this in Excel 2019 but you'll have to swap `SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))` for `ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)))`

[image]

Comment: I believe this is ideal. Is it possible to get the formula to ignore blank cells?

Comment: @asd213e1, sure. But in what way? Just add an `IF` in front to check for empty cells first I'd say.

Comment: I have been attempting to use this formula, however keep getting the #VALUE! error message: https://i.imgur.com/1sNfdIq.png
Would you happen to know if there is a problem? 
In regards to the blank cells, simple so it doesn't show #VALUE! on every non-entry.

Comment: @asd213e1, I'm not seeing a very clear error in your formula from this screenshot. Maybe share the actual formula and I'll check it on some data.

Comment: It was the exact formula you had posted

Comment: Then maybe the exact data in `A1` that is the issue?

Comment: It is the exact same as your image. Does onedrive excel sheets support dynamic arrays?

Comment: Can you share your file?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoeqcVj5v9JTgfoJ1iLSjvZGY2ez8Q?e=h9dFOb

Comment: Right, filterxml is not supported in Excel online

Comment: That must be the issue then. I will have to see if I can get a copy of 365 to try the formula.

Answer (score 0):

This formula won't work in many cases, but if the string has matching rules as in your example, then try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C5,"「" & INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&SUBSTITUTE(C5,"」","「"),"「",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(A1:INDEX(A1:A100,LEN(C5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C5,"」",""))))*2-1)*99,99)),MATCH("*―*/*",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&SUBSTITUTE(C5,"」","「"),"「",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(A1:INDEX(A1:A100,LEN(C5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C5,"」",""))))*2-1)*99,99)),0)) & "」","")
```

[image]

explain how it works:

1. split the string between the characters `"「 "and "」"` into an array
2. use `match("*―*/*",,0)` to find the string position (note that it will only return one value if it exists, if you have multiple strings, you can replace `match("*―*/*",)` with `search ("*―*/*",..)` and use it as an extra column to get matches string)
3. Use the `index(array,match("*―*/*",..))` to get the string needs replacing (result)
4. Replace the original string with the results found `=substitute(txt,result,"")`

Comment: There are sometimes multiple cases of「sentence―sentence/sentence」in the one cell. Will this formula work over a range with multiple blank cells at random?

Comment: all matches string are the same will be replaced, if the strings have the same format (but  different eg: 「sentence―sentence/sentence」and 「sent―sent/sent」) it will only work for the all first match string.

Answer (score 0):

Or,

In B1 enter formula :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"「"&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("」",A1,FIND("/",A1))),"「",REPT(" ",99)),99)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: How would you edit this formula to also affect multiple strings in the one cell for example: `text <br>（１）text。「―text」「sentence(sentence)―sentence/sentence（sentence）」<br>（２）text。「sentence，―sentence(sentence)sentence/sentence（sentence）」`
At the moment, it will only affect the first sentence part

Comment: This formula cannot remove 2nd sentence part, so ignore to my formula.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tag **[VBA]**, but if you are not averse, you could write a User Defined Function that would do what you want using Regular Expressions.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=replStr(A1)` in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function replStr(str As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\u300C(?:(?=[^\u300D]*\u002F)(?=[^\u300D]*\u2015)[^\u300D]*)\u300D"
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    replStr = .Replace(str, "")
End With
End Function
```

[image]